# postgres add partitioning support on non partitioned table

Tags: postgresql

I have existing table which has become too large and I would like to enable partitions for the current year from timestamp field. How can I do this, I can't find anything in the documentation, is it not possible to make a table partitioned after creation?

ALTER TABLE appointment PARTITION BY RANGE (start_on) -> does not work.

Comment: I don't think it is possible the way you are trying. Try copying the data for each range to new tables (each of which will become a partition later) possibly with check constraints on `start_on`, recreate your table as a partition table, then to a `ALTER TABLE... ATTACH PARTITION ...` Obviously, try it outside of production environment first.

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE):

> It is not possible to turn a regular table into a partitioned table or vice versa. However, it is possible to add an existing regular or partitioned table as a partition of a partitioned table, or remove a partition from a partitioned table turning it into a standalone table...

So you might want to create a new partitioned table, and attach the old one as a (default) partition to it.

Answer (score 0):

You would want something like:

```
alter table appointment add constraint starton check (start_on >= $1 and start_on < $2) not valid;
alter table appointment validate constraint starton;
create table new_appt (like appointment) partition by range (start_on);
alter table new_appt attach partition appointment for values from ($1) to ($2);
```

It will probably be more complex, as you will also need to deal with indexes, foreign keys, etc.  Of course you need to provide $1 and $2 to be at least as wide as the existing range in the table.